# Django finds index.html template, but no others

Tags: python, django, templates, static

I'm working on a website that has a few static pages. Django is able to find static files just fine, except for templates. I'm using a base html file (`basesite.html`) that each template extends. `index.html` is found and displayed correctly, but the rest of the templates just displays the `basesite.html` section and none of the custom block content for each page. This even happens for the Django default Admin page.

`basesite.html` loads static files, some local CSS and JavaScript, fonts over the Internet from Google Fonts, and prepares the navbar for the site.

I've tried a few configurations for static and template definitions in `settings.py`, and I believe I have them configured correctly. I don't understand how Django is able to find `index.html` but none of the other templates, which are all stored in the same directory.

This is my directory hierarchy:

```
├── blog
├── db.sqlite3
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── files
│   ├── images
│   └── js
└── templates
    ├── admin
    │   └── base_site.html
    ├── basesite.html
    ├── blog
    │   └── blogpost_list.html
    ├── contact.html
    ├── index.html
    └── projects.html
```

Here is some relevant stuff from `settings.py`:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))   

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

My `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
    url(r'^projects/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="projects.html")),
    url(r'^contact/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="contact.html")),
    url(r'^.*$', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Each template has the following:

```
{% extends "basesite.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Some HTML...</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the debugging information when you try to access the relevant paths?

Comment: Each route just returns HTTP 200.

Comment: please try to put a "$" at the end of your url regexes like: url(r'^projects/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="projects.html"))

Comment: @Jingo Same result, unfortunately.

Comment: What happens when you replace your first url template_name argument with `template_name="projects.html"`? Does it still work?

Comment: @cziemba Instead of seeing the template for `index.html`, it shows me the `projects.html` page. The other pages still display just the navbar from `basesite.html` though.

Answer (score 0):

The `index.html`, `contact.html` and similar files related to your app named '`blog`', should go inside `<workdir>templates/blog/`

Comment: Those templates are separate from that app.

Comment: ok, and shudn't we add 'blog' app in INSTALLED_APPS list, settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the trailing slashes from the urlpatterns, and the templates are used as intended. Might not be the best fix, but we'll see.